# How can I use ORDER BY column_string like column_int when my column_string have letters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like:

```
------------------
| ID  |  Animal  |
------------------
|  1  |    B1    |
------------------
|  2  |    B2    |
------------------
|  3  |    B3    |
------------------
|  4  |    B4    |
------------------
|  5  |    B5    |
------------------
|  6  |     1    |
------------------
|  7  |     2    |
------------------
|  8  |    R71   |
------------------
|  9  |    R72   |
------------------
|  10  |    4    |
------------------
| 11   |    7    |
------------------
| 12   |    R1   |
------------------
| 13   |    77   |
------------------
| 14   |    3    |
------------------
| 15   |    5    |
------------------
| 16   |    R2   |
------------------
| 17   |    T3   |
------------------
| 18   |    C50  |
------------------
| 19   |    R5   |
------------------
| 20   |    R6   |
------------------
```

My DB is shared hosted where I don't have any possibility to set new configurations and, until last week, my query with final ORDER BY animal + 0 ASC was returning the result orderly, like: B1...B5, R1...R72, 1...700. Yesterday our database returned all results, with the same query, disorderly while, in developer DB, it's returned orderly as always.

I consult the host service, but it affirms there's no problem with DB and it doesn't have new configuration.

I tried to use CAST() and CONVERT() function, but it returned animal disorderly.

Can someone shed light on this issue?

Comment: What ordering would you like to get? Can you add the expect output to the question?

Comment: Good morning, Mr. @Mureinik. I would like to get something like B1...B5, R1...R72, 1...700 (ASC); or R72...R1, B5...B1, 700...1 (DESC). Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For this sample data this will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY Animal + 0, 
         CASE WHEN Animal + 0 = 0 THEN LEFT(Animal, 1) END,
         CASE WHEN Animal + 0 = 0 THEN SUBSTR(Animal, 2) + 0 END
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e419a138aad9ef296ab4648f37fa1687).
Results:

```
> ID | Animal
> -: | :-----
>  1 | B1    
>  2 | B2    
>  3 | B3    
>  4 | B4    
>  5 | B5    
> 18 | C50   
> 12 | R1    
> 16 | R2    
> 19 | R5    
> 20 | R6    
>  8 | R71   
>  9 | R72   
> 17 | T3    
>  6 | 1     
>  7 | 2     
> 14 | 3     
> 10 | 4     
> 15 | 5     
> 11 | 7     
> 13 | 77
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. @forpas. I tried your method and was successful. Realy, I don't understand to mutch how it's happend, but I will study (laughing).

I was read the manual and I don't understand what happend. Here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html. See: wheter I write ORDER BY animal, id ASC, that returned the result orderly to. But whether I change ASC por DESC, the order is applied only in animal names with letters (A...Z). I tried your method with DESC and it returned the same. I can't understand... (laughing)

Very thanks!

Comment: Mr. @forpas, see de demo with addition of ID and DESC: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3d45bfe08ddc9fa97b87501e86fee193
With your method and DESC: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e70f5834baeaef6897c5e02acaa62d75

Comment: The column ID is of no importance in this requirement. As I understand, you want to sort first all the non numeric Animals and then the numeric ones.

Comment: Yes, Mr. @forpas. I used him because it's a Index. I understand, reading the manual, that would do something. My english is not so good... It was like a "shoot at the darkness" (free translate from portuguese term).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the initial string is just one letter and there is no zero padding of the numbers, you can do:

```
order by (case when left(animal, 1) not between '0' and '9'
               then left(animal, 1) else 'ZZ'
          end),
         length(animal) desc,
         animal
```

If the initial strings are longer, you can still do something similar, but the logic is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thank You, Mr. @Gordon Linoff. I try your method, but returns "Erro SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')". Maybe Ia did some error.

Comment: @gmc_pecas . . . The syntax is fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7654011904b2564cc58ebec8a6c122d.

Comment: @gmc_pecas . . . I'm surprised you didn't accept this answer, assuming that it actually does do what you want (which I think it does).

Comment: Mr. @Gordon Linoff, I'm sorry. I should have mentioned this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6ceddaec81b13dcb7d66df8eeb17b6ae
I tried to apply your model in another DB and it returns similar.
Thank You.